# AWS Amplify: Verify updated email address while not being authenticated

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

When my users update their email address on the settings page of my application, I send them an email with a link to `mydomain.com/verify_email?username=COGNITO_USERNAME&code=123456`. When a user clicks on the link in the email, the user's default browser will open the specified page, which, in turn, will parse the URL and call `Auth.verifyCurrentUserAttributeSubmit('email', code)` (it does not use the search parameter `username` specified the URL).

However, this process only works if the user is authenticated, i.e. if the user's email client opens a browser tab or window on a device and browser where the user has previously signed in since any call to `verifyCurrentUserAttributeSubmit` needs to authenticated (see [Amplify source](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js/src/CognitoUser.js#L1729)).

How can I verify updated user attributes (preferably using Amplify) without requiring users to be signed in so that they can confirm updated attributes using another device or browser?